# What is the Sheikah Slate update you get from Symin?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

To give context of where in the game my question comes into play: When you go to Hateno tech lab, after lighting the blue flame, Purah uses the pedestal to download the Camera Rune, which comes with 12 ancient pictures already taken. After that, you can upgrade your Sheika Slate Seeker to the Seeker+, where you can track items in the Compendium.

After doing the Seeking Sunshrooms sidequest for Symin, when you talk to him again, he says something along the lines of upgrading your compendium (or your slate) to allow something related to helping you find the locations in the ancient photos.

He puts your slate in the pedestal again, and it does the download thing again. A messages says (I think) "Hyrule Compendium updated". Purah says that from now on she will have to charge you to do this. However... after this happens, I can't see any difference in the camera or the compendium! There are no new compendium entries; only the ones I had manually taken pictures of. No ability to use the seeker+ to find the ancient picture locations or anything.

**What was it that was downloaded to the Sheika Slate when Symin puts it in the pedestal?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I'm understanding your situation correctly, what you're talking about isn't actually an upgrade.

What was downloaded was a new entry for your Hyrule Compendium. Take another look at it - there should be a picture inside there somewhere that you didn't actually take.

From now on, you have the ability to unlock as many pictures for the Hyrule Compendium as you want, just by talking to Symin. It will randomly add pictures of things you haven't found yet. The only downside is that you'll have to pay 100 rupees for every single one. It's basically just an alternative way to fill up your compendium if you have a lot of cash and don't feel like going around taking pictures all the time.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to double-check this tonight. I thought I looked and saw that the only entries there were the ones I'd taken pictures of, but I already had a dozen or so pictures I'd taken, so it's possible I missed one. Would it have just been a random entry?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure the "free sample" is chosen at random just like the entries you can buy afterwards.

Comment: Confirmed; I hadn't noticed it previously because it was just a type of shroom; among a few other shrooms that I had taken pictures of. Thanks!

Comment: it's worth adding that you select a category of image to purchase, so the picture isn't completely random. For example, you can choose between a random weapon picture or a random creature picture.

Comment: After you've beaten Ganon once (and have the little star next to your save file), you can also purchase photos of "strong enemies" for 500 rupees each.